# Rabbitmq headers exchange and confirmed delivery

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm trying to use headers exchange on RabbitMQ, with mixed java and python components, and I need confirmed delivery.

I seem to get different a behaviour from the python (pika) and java clients.

In python:

```
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='headers_test',
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦type='headers',
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦durable=True)
channel.confirm_delivery()
result = channel.basic_publish(exchange='headers_test',
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦ routing_key='',
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦ mandatory=True,
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦ body=message,
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦ properties=pika.BasicProperties(
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦ delivery_mode=2,
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦ headers=message_headers))
```

If the headers don't match any bound consumer and the message cannot be routed, **result is false**

But in java/scala:

```
channel.exchangeDeclare("headers_test", "headers", true, false, null)
channel.confirmSelect

val props = MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC.builder
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦  .headers(messageHeaders).build
channel.basicPublish("headers_test", 
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦"", //routingKey
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦true, //mandatory
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦props, 
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦"data".getBytes)
channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie()
```

Here, when messageHeaders don't find a match, the **message seems to just be dropped without an error**.

Am I missing something or the behaviour of both clients really is different? And how can I get confirmed delivery using headers exchange in java?

Note: I already have a "complex" exchange to queues routing setup, I would rather avoid adding dead-letters routing to the game, and just fail-on-send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that a message is considered confirmed even if there's no queue matching your headers. From the docs (https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html):

> For unroutable messages, the broker will issue a confirm once the
>   exchange verifies a message won't route to any queue (returns an empty
>   list of queues). If the message is also published as mandatory, the
>   basic.return is sent to the client before basic.ack. The same is true
>   for negative acknowledgements (basic.nack).

Instead you should be checking for a basic.return message to detect if a message has been routed or not.

I've checked with wireshark, and indeed I can see that if a message is not routed there's an AMQP basic.return message.

I supppose you should start with

```
channel.addReturnListener(new ReturnListener() {
  @Override
  public void handleReturn(int replyCode, String replyText, String exchange, String routingKey, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("App.handleReturn");
    System.out.println("replyCode = [" + replyCode + "], replyText = [" + replyText + "], exchange = [" + exchange + "], routingKey = [" + routingKey + "], properties = [" + properties + "], body = [" + body + "]");
  }
});
```

And indeed if a message hasn't been routed I get this:

> replyCode = [312], replyText = [NO_ROUTE], exchange = [headers_logs],
>   routingKey = [], pro....

Furthermore, if you want to emulate Pika's synchronous behavior in Java it seems you can do it by taking a current publish sequence number before publishing a message and registering a confirmation listener instead of relying on .waitForConfirmsOrDie().

So a full code sample would be:

```
channel.addReturnListener(new ReturnListener() {
      @Override
      public void handleReturn(int replyCode, String replyText, String exchange, String routingKey, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("App.handleReturn");
        System.out.println("replyCode = [" + replyCode + "], replyText = [" + replyText + "], exchange = [" + exchange + "], routingKey = [" + routingKey + "], properties = [" + properties + "], body = [" + body + "]");
      }
    });

    channel.addConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {
      @Override
      public void handleAck(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("App.handleAck");
        System.out.println("deliveryTag = [" + deliveryTag + "], multiple = [" + multiple + "]");
      }

      @Override
      public void handleNack(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("App.handleNack");
        System.out.println("deliveryTag = [" + deliveryTag + "], multiple = [" + multiple + "]");
      }
});

long nextPublishSeqNo = channel.getNextPublishSeqNo();
System.out.println("nextPublishSeqNo = " + nextPublishSeqNo);

channel.basicPublish("headers_logs",
    "",
     true,
     props,
    "data".getBytes());
```

And inside of the return/confirm callback you need to look for a channel's publish sequence number you got before publishing a message.

If you look at what happens on the wire, in case if a message hasn't been routed to any queue, RabbitMq sends back a single basic.return message which also contains a confirmation (delivery tag). If a message has been routed, RabbitMq sends back a single bacic.ack message which also contains a confirmation.

It seems that RabbitMq Java client always calls basicReturn() callback before a basicConfirm(), so a logic to determine if a message has been routed or not can be this:

Register return and confirm listeners on a channel;
Memorize a channel's next publish sequence number;
Wait for either a return or a confirm callback. If it's a return callback - a message has not been routed, and you should ignore a further confirmation for the same delivery tag. If you receive a handleAck() callback before you receive a handleReturn() it means a message has been routed to a queue.

Though I am not sure in which case can .handleNack() be called.